# A bounded domain can be considered as a compact manifold?

Tags: analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

A bounded domain $\Omega$  with smooth boundary $\Gamma$ can be considered as a compact connect Riemannian manifold?

Answer (score 5):

Domains are open, so not compact. If you throw in the boundary to make it compact, it will no longer be a manifold (though it will be a manifold with boundary, since $\Gamma$ is smooth).